# Calling different C functions according to the C++ template type

Tags: c++, c, templates, macros

my problem is the following:
I have a C library which contain several versions of each function according to which data type they are working with e.g.:

```
void add(double *a, double *b, double *c);
```

and

```
void sadd(float *a, float *b, float *c);
```

Now, having an external C++ template function, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
template<class T>
void myfunc(/*params*/)
{
 // Obtain a,b,c of type T* from params

/*
 If T is double call add(a,b,c);
 else if T is float call sadd(a,b,c).
*/ 
}
```

I am aware that It can be done by specialized template functions like:

```
template<>
void myfunc<double>(/*params*/)
{
  // Obtain a,b,c of type double* from params
  add(a,b,c);
}
```

and so on, but it is not really an option since the whole point of introducing the templated C++ function was to reduce code repetition and the "// Obtain a,b,c of type T* from params" part can be really long.

Does this problem have a simple solution?

Thanks

Zdenek

Comment: you can use polymorphism functions

Comment: The short answer is no. If the code was all C++, so you overloaded `add` for `double *` and `float *` params, that would work, but with "hand overloading" using separate names for each, you're also going to have to generate the calling code for each separately.

Comment: The point of templates here is not just "to reduce code". The most important part here is type deduction.

Comment: Or you can use function pointers (with downsides). But you'll have to list (repeat) the names of the C functions somewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was afraid of. I think I can do simple C++ template wrapper for the C library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define overloaded C++ forwarders:

```
inline void forward_add(double *a, double *b, double *c) { add( a, b, c ); }
inline void forward_add(float *a, float *b, float *c) { sadd( a, b, c ); }

template<class T>
void myfunc(/*params*/)
{
   // Obtain a,b,c of type T* from params
   forward_add( a, b, c );
}
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to pass by `const` reference to the templated function.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Not in case of the OPs C functions. There might be other cases where this should be considered, but here it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Well, the myfunc should not be even aware of sadd, as it requires adding more boilerplate code when adding support for more data types and I need something universal for all functions from the C library.

Comment: @DanielFrey True. If he needs to deal with rvalues he can just overload `myfunc` and go about his merry way.

Comment: @ZdenekPrusa `myfunc` is only aware of `forward_add`, you just limit the visibility of `sadd` to the one-line forwarder. You will have to specify `sadd` somewhere. Or maybe I don't fully understand your requirements... :-/

Comment: +1 Good answer, but I guess not good enough when the OP wants magic. How can you possibly expect a solution that never ever mentions add and sadd, @ZdenekPrusa?

Comment: @JimBalter I do not want magic. I will probably end up using Daniel's solution btw. thank you for that Daniel ;). In plain C, I did sometring like this. I included file containing myfunc (no template now) twice. First time setting macros `#define T double` and `#define FNAME(name) name` and second time with `#define T float` and `#define FNAME(name) s##name` allowing me to write `FNAME(add)` only once. I just thought that there is something better in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you have to tell the compiler that `sadd` and `add` are related.

One approach is a traits class
    template
    struct math;

```
template<>
struct math<double> {
  static void add(double *a, double *b, double *c) {
    return ::add(a, b, c);
  }
};
template<>
struct math<float> {
  static void add(float*a, float*b, float*c) {
    return ::sadd(a, b, c);
  }
};
```

where you use it like:

```
template<class T>
void myfunc(/*params*/)
{
  // Obtain a,b,c of type T* from params

  math<T>::add( a, b, c );
}
```

this has the advantage and disadvantage of putting all of your type-based refactoring into one spot.

Another approach is to create free standing C++ functions with overloads for `double` and `float`.  This has the advantage and disadvantage of allowing your code to be spread over multiple spots.

```
void math_add( double* a, double* b, double* c ) {
  add(a,b,c);
}
void math_add( float* a, float* b, float* c ) {
  sadd(a,b,c);
}
```

Now, suppose all of your functions share the same pattern of name -- `foo` for `double` and `sfoo` for `float`.  In that case, text based code generation can be used to ease some of the above "write an overload" code.

The only issue here is that the signatures of the functions can vary.  If there are only a handful, simple macros would work:

```
#define MAKE_FUNCS( f ) \
  void CONCAT( math_, f ) ( double* a, double* b, double * c ) { \
    f ( a, b, c ); \
  } \
  void CONCAT( math_, f ) ( float* a, float* b, float* c ) { \
    CONCAT( f, s ) ( a, b, c ); \
  }
```

then just spam out `MAKE_FUNCS` for each function in your library you are trying to clone this way.

A downside (among many) is that it only supports a fixed set of signatures.  We can fix this via perfect forwarding, a C++11 technique:

```
#define MAKE_FUNCS( f ) \
  template< typename... Args >\
  auto f ( Args&&... args ) \
    -> decltype(::f ( std::forward<Args>(args)... )) \
  { \
    ::f ( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); \
  } \
  template< typename... Args >\
  auto f ( Args&&... args ) \
    -> decltype(:: CONCAT( f, s ) ( std::forward<Args>(args)... )) \
  { \
    :: CONCAT( f, s ) ( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); \
  }
```

but this runs into SFINAE and identical signature problems.  You can fix this by explicit expression SFINAE:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

#define CONCAT2( a, b ) a##b
#define CONCAT( a, b ) CONCAT2(a,b)

// SFINAE helper boilerplate:
template<typename T> struct is_type:std::true_type {};
template<std::size_t n> struct secret_enum { enum class type {}; };
template<bool b, std::size_t n>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if< b, typename secret_enum<n>::type >::type;

// Macro that takes a srcF name and a dstF name and an integer N and
// forwards arguments matching dstF's signature.  An integer N must be
// passed in with a distinct value for each srcF of the same name:
#define FORWARD_FUNC( srcF, dstF, N ) \
template< typename... Args, \
  EnableIf< is_type< \
    decltype( dstF ( std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())... )) \
  >::value , N >... > \
auto srcF ( Args&&... args ) \
  -> decltype(dstF ( std::forward<Args>(args)... )) \
{ \
  dstF ( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); \
}

#define MAKE_FUNCS( f ) \
  FORWARD_FUNC( f, ::f, 0 ) \
  FORWARD_FUNC( f, :: CONCAT( f, s ), 1 )

void add( double* a, double* b, double* c) {*a = *b+*c;}
void adds( float* a, float* b, float* c) {*a = *b+*c;}
namespace math {
  MAKE_FUNCS(add)
}
int main() {
  double a, b = 2, c = 3;
  float af, bf = 3, cf = 5;
  math::add( &a, &b, &c );
  math::add( &af, &bf, &cf );
  std::cout << a << "=" << b << "+" << c << "\n";
  std::cout << af << "=" << bf << "+" << cf << "\n";
}
```

but as you can see, this is getting pretty obtuse, and there are not many compilers that can handle this level of C++11isms at this point.  (I think the above should compile in gcc 4.8 and intel's latest, but not MSVC or clang 3.2)

Now you simply take each function in your library, and do a header file consisting of a pile of single-line boilerplate:

```
namespace mymath {
  MAKE_FUNCS( add )
  MAKE_FUNCS( sub )
  MAKE_FUNCS( chicken )
}
#undef MAKE_FUNCS
```

which you then call by saying `mymath::add` instead of `add` or `adds`.

This could also be done by other forms of textual code generation.

Comment: In your first `MAKE_FUNCS` macro, shouldn't the second function have `float` parameters?

Comment: @ZdenekPrusa ya, it is a bit of a mess: Macros creating C++11 perfect forwarding SFINAE functions. I would avoid it as a solution, simply because nobody could figure out what it was doing... The only plus side is that, after all the hackery, the code that uses the hackery looks pretty. :)

Comment: @ZdenekPrusa made the template spew more understandable, and commented!

Comment: @Yakk did you test your code? There's at least a typo `true_tupe` and something weird about using the function parameter in the template parameter. Edit: the second template parameter is not a template parameter at all o.O

Comment: @DyP test code?  What tomfoolery is that. I just wrote it from my head without a compiler, what harm could that cause?... Ok ok, tested, tpyos and bugs fixed.  The ridiculous(tm) version now [builds and runs](https://ideone.com/81Lw9H).

Comment: I see now. Tricky! +1 Btw you found a way to "overload" functions that only differ by return type o.O (calling them implicitly will be ambiguous, though)